# How to filter documents in a collection when inside an array in Arangodb?

Tags: arangodb

I am  going through the [tutorial on Arangodb](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/tutorial-filter.html) which is using a sample game of thrones dataset. I am trying to figure out how I would be able to filter out characters based on a trait?

```
 INSERT {
    "name": "Ned",
    "surname": "Stark",
    "alive": true,
    "age": 41,
    "traits": ["A","H","C","N","P"]
} INTO Characters
```

I am trying to use the following code but its not working. Would the above traits be an array. if so how do I proceed?

```
for c in Characters
Filter c.traits =="A"
RETURN c
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find all characters that *have* trait "A" you can use `FILTER "A" IN c.traits`, i.e., the characters may also have other traits. If you want to find characters that have *only* trait "A" you can use `FILTER c.trait == ["A"]`.

Comment: Suppose I wanted to filter characters with  A and M? FILTER "A" AND "M" in c.traits is giving me an error

Comment: You can use `ALL IN` - see https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/operators.html#array-comparison-operators